# How to show leaderboard in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, game-center

I am using sprite-kit and targeted iOS 7. I want to show leaderboard with button in my MenuScene.

my helper method codes.

```
#import "GameKitHelper.h"

NSString *const PresentAuthenticationViewController =
@"present_authentication_view_controller";

@interface GameKitHelper()<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation GameKitHelper {
    BOOL _enableGameCenter;
}

+ (instancetype)sharedGameKitHelper
{
    static GameKitHelper *sharedGameKitHelper;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedGameKitHelper = [[GameKitHelper alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedGameKitHelper;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _enableGameCenter = YES;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)showGKGameCenterViewController:
(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (!_enableGameCenter) {
        NSLog(@"Local play is not authenticated");
    }
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterViewController =
    [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    gameCenterViewController.viewState =
    GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
    [viewController presentViewController:gameCenterViewController
                                 animated:YES
                               completion:nil];
}
```

I want to Leaderboard Button in this class.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"start"]) {
        MyScene *myScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:myScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.5]];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"gameCenter"]) {
        //HERE MY LEADERBOARD BUTTON ACTION
        //I don't know what i write here...
   {
}
```

I tried so much methods but these working in iOS 6, I targeted iOS 7.
I tried this: 
`[[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] showGKGameCenterViewController:self];` Xcode says for self 
`Incompatible pointer types sending 'GameMenuScene *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I dont know. What I write in MY LEADERBOARD BUTTON I ACTION. I know its easy question, this is my first game center experience. If u answer me i make happy :)

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: how can i go to Game Center leaderboard with my button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrey is right. gameKitHelper means [gameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper]. like this example

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"gameCenter"]) {
        UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
        [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] showGKGameCenterViewController:vc];
    }
```

Keep coding :)

Comment: Wow it is working, thanks :). Andrey answered but i didnt understand

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"gameCenter"]) {
    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] showGKGameCenterViewController:vc];
}
```

But actually you should present another ViewController from your ViewController, not from `SKScene`

Comment: What is the gameKitHelperInstance?

Comment: That is an instance of `GameKitHelper` class

Comment: I don't know what is my instance name it doesn't work. I will update my gamekithelper.m please help me

Comment: I updated more details about my gameKitHelper. If u talking about sharedGameKit helper it doesn't work Xcode can't find this.

Comment: Classes and objects are a very basics of iOS development and definitely out of scope of this question. You should read more about that. You can start from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html

Comment: I can't using self in myscene how can i show leaderboard.I tried this: [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] showGKGameCenterViewController:self]; Xcode says for self "Incompatible pointer types sending 'GameMenuScene *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's easy to implement and works well:

https://github.com/nihalahmed/GameCenterManager

inside viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(openLeaderboard) 
    name:@"TestNotification"
    object:nil];
```

Inside VC:

```
   - (void) openLeaderboard
{

    // Open Leaderboards here


}
```

In your Scene:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:self];
```

Comment: I can't use it, I am using sprite-kit. I have 3 scene in one view controller. I tried this: [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] showGKGameCenterViewController:self];
Xcode says for self "Incompatible pointer types sending 'GameMenuScene *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'"

Comment: Setup a NSNotification. Inside the viewController that show the SKScene create a method that open the Leaderboards. Then inside the SKScene create a method that call that NSNotification(See the above code)

Comment: NSNOTIFICATION is bad idea for performance. By the way thanks i fixed already :)